# how to add onclick javascript for Dictionary<string, string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections, dictionary

I have a Dictionary object in my view as

```
<% System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> param= new Dictionary<string, string>();; %>
<% {
    param.Add("id","AdditionalPrincipalAmount");
    param.Add("onblur", "TotalPaymentAmount()");
}  %>
```

does JavaScript call only work for `Dictionary<string, object>` or does it also work for  `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Could you please try to restate this question?  It's really confusing as it currently is written, and I doubt you are going to get any useful answers until it is rewritten.

Comment: Can a dictionary be used as a control? Also, if this is MVC, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a dictionary here in your C# code however you don't seem to be doing anything with it.

The Dictionary itself is never present on the front end to the browser which is the main realm of Javascript.

Basically, Javascript has no knowlege of the Dictionary you create in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but I don't think you can add an onclick event to a dictionary. A dictionary is a collection, not a control. Not very knowledgable when it comes to MVC, but it doesn't seem logical...